# keep URL same and load content of different website

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have first.abc.com/xyz (xyz being an application under main domain abc.com) that needs to load content off of a different website second.abc.com/whatever/xyz while keeping the URL same to first.abc.com/xyz how is this possible? I have looked into a couple videos for reverseproxy with ARR, but I am not an expert on servers. Hope I am clear on the issue at hand. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install

1. IIS URL rewrite module
2. IIS ARR routing for reverse proxy using

then add the routing in web.config ,or add in the applicationhost.config

here is the example

```
<rule name="ReverseProxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(xyz)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://first.abc.com/xyz" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```